# Stationary solution to a inhomogeneous differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use the Transfer function to determine the stationary solution.

Given:

$$y'''(t) +4y''(t)+9y'+10y(t) = 2e^{-3t}\cos(t)$$

I have determined the transfer function to

$$H(s)=\frac{2}{s^{3}+4s^{2}+9s+10}$$

I have attempted to use the theory below to determine the stationary solution but without any success. I would appreciate some help to figure this out. What I have tried does not give me the correct solution.

Correct solution:

$$y_{p}(t)=-0.04615384615 \cdot e^{-3t} \cdot \cos(t) +0.1692307692 \cdot e^{-3t} \cdot \sin(t)$$

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right side of your equation is the real part of $2e^{(-3+i)t}$. The transfer function does not contain parts of the right side, it is just $H(s)=(s^3+4s^2+9s+10)^{-1}$, so that your solution is obtained as the real part of $2H(-3+i)e^{(-3+i)t}$. What remains is to compute the complex numbers in that expression, giving something like $\frac{2e^{(-3+i)t}}{-3+11i}$, then make the denominator real and read off the real part.

Comment: Thank you for explanation I finally it understand now ! Good day to you !